# Can you save my friends and me?

Tags: pattern, letters

Don't ask me how we got there, I don't know myself! 
The thing is, I was hanging with a bunch of friends, when all of a sudden, we find ourselves on a planet full of Schmulrogs! Damn, 
these head-chopping aliens won't let us go, unless we play one of their stupid game! Oh wait, one of them is coming.

> -- Ahem... Hello humans, can you tell me your names?
>
> -- There is Dave, Harry, Nancy, Mike, Sam, Kimber and I'm Wendy. What do you want from us?
>
> -- You're Wendy? Interesting. I'll tell the others.

Argh, he's gone, what a waste of time! But hey, we're not complaining, they haven't chopped our heads off yet...

> -- I'm back! Ok, let's play a game! We'll associate a letter to each one of you, except for Wendy. And you know what? Your goal will be to associate a letter to Wendy! But if the letter doesn't fit, well, you know, we'll kill you...
>   -- Wait, fit *what*?
>   -- Sorry, I can't tell much. Here are your letters.
>
> Dave, you are associated with the letter S.
>   Harry, you get the letter P.
>   Nancy, the F.
>   Mike, the letter L.
>   Sam, you get the H.
>   Kimber, the letter T.
>
> That's it, be logical, and see you in half an hour!
>
> -- WHAT?!

He's already gone. Why me? I don't even know what we are looking for! Can you help us *fast*?

Comment: I'm already hooked by the Schmulrogs' 2 favorite pastimes - brutal decapitation and tricky word puzzles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

> B

because

> when you replace the first letter of the person's name with the associated letter, you get an English word:  
>
> - Dave + S = Save
> - Harry + P = Parry
> - Nancy + F = Fancy
> - Mike + L = Like
> - Sam + H = Ham
> - Kimber + T = Timber  
>  and
> - **Wendy + B = Bendy**

Comment: Why would Dave be S instead of G or P or W? This seems to be one of many possible answers, but it doesn't seem to fit tightly enough to be obviously correct.

Comment: @Sconibulus good question, but 'bendy' is the only word fitting the pattern for Wendy. I think that's what counts, but we'll see soon enough if this answer gets accepted or not.

Comment: The real puzzle here is who the heck's named Kimber

Comment: @user1566694 short for Kimberley, I guess.

Comment: I wonder what would've happened if they brought their black friend, L'Quanjika

Comment: @user1566694 They would have given Wendy a letter and begin decapitations in a half hour.

Comment: That's it. The idea is that the *W* can only be changed by a *B*.

Comment: Also, head-chopper was a slight clue in order to 'play' with the first letter (the *head* of the word).